# AltBeacon Setting Bluetooth Name

Tags: android, bluetooth, altbeacon

I am putting together an app for demo/testing purposes that will allow my team to use their phones as a beacon using the AltBeacon advertising functionality.  I have successfully gotten advertising to function on my Nexus 6P running Android API 23 using the following code, but I have not been able to "detect" a beacon with the Bluetooth name that I've assigned.  It always comes up "N/A" for the local name.

```
//Beacon stuff
private Beacon mBeacon;
private BeaconParser mBeaconParser;
private BeaconTransmitter mBeaconTransmitter;
private String estimoteBeaconLayout = "m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24";
```

Here's the code from my method that starts advertising

```
//creating the beacon object based on the user input
    mBeacon = new Beacon.Builder()
            .setId1(inputUUID)
            .setId2(inputMinor)
            .setId3(inputMajor)
            .setManufacturer(0x004C)
            .setTxPower(-59)
            .setRssi(-80)
            .setBeaconTypeCode(02)
            .setBluetoothName("TestName")
            //.setDataFields(Arrays.asList(new Long[]{0l}))
            .build();

    //creating the beacon parser and setting it to the user specified format
    mBeaconParser = new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(estimoteBeaconLayout);

    //setting up the beacon transmitter
    mBeaconTransmitter = new BeaconTransmitter(getContext(), mBeaconParser);

    //starting advertising
    mBeaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(mBeacon, new AdvertiseCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
            updateDebugTextWindow("Advertising Started");
            super.onStartSuccess(settingsInEffect);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartFailure(int errorCode) {
            updateDebugTextWindow("Advertising start failed");
            super.onStartFailure(errorCode);
        }
    });
```

and here's a screen shot from my Nexus 5 running Nordic's nRF Master app

[Nexus 5 Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJRKt.png)

Any tips on how to get the local name to work would be appreciated